# Find record by lat / lon in rails-postgres-rgeo project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geometry, postgis, rgeo

Having Table `Neighborhoods`, which looks like this:

```
id: 1,
title: "Sun City",
state: "CA",
geometry: "MULTIPOLYGON (((-117.1935499999999 33.74306900000005, -117.1935729999999 33.74198700000005, -117.19369999999992 33.73596500000008, -117.18936799999994 33.73584000000005, -117.18935499999992 33.72862400000008, -117.18935399999992 33.72801800000008, -117.18925499999995 33.72163400000005, -117.18921699999993 33.719152000000065, -117.18921699999993 33.71860200000009, -117.18910699999992 33.717250000000035, -117.18907999999993 33.715738000000044, -117.18896999999993 33.71498200000008, -117.18896999999993 33.71418100000005, -117.18866899999995 33.712829000000056, -117.18855899999994 33.71266900000006, -117.18844899999993 33.711959000000036, ...
```

`geometry` - is a big set of lon/lat pairs.
I want to be able to find Neighborhood by `lat` and `lon`.

Right now Im using this method:

```
def is_within_or_intersects?(lat, lon)
  factory = RGeo::Cartesian.factory
  point = factory.point(lon, lat)
  boundary = factory.parse_wkt(self.geometry)
  point.intersects?(boundary) || point.within?(boundary)
end
```

But that method is slow and to use I need do load all and loop through each `Neighoborhood`.

Better to have some sql query to load neighborhoods with specified `lat/lon` right away, rather than looping through all.

I tried this (Lat Lon are hardcoded for example):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM neighborhoods WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geometry, 2263), 4326), ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(-117.18757899999991 33.709771000000046)', 4326))")
```

But I get this:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function st_setsrid(character varying, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: ...FROM neighborhoods WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 1):

An error is returned because your geometry field is not a geometry type field. Your data is just text field in WKT/EWKT format.
Cast your text field to geometry type first and should work.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM neighborhoods 
 WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(st_geomfromtext(geometry), 2263), 4326), 
                   ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(-117.18757899999991 33.709771000000046)', 4326))")
```

If I can advise you should change your data type for geometry data(which you have as an text filed with WKT text) to GEOGRAPHY type (as you work with SRID 4326 it will be the best and easiest way to work with PostGIS functions)
Also you can easily return data from GEOGRAPHY/GEOMETRY type to WKT/EWKT with PostGIS functions st_astext() st_asewkt().

With GEOGRAPHY/GEOMETRY formats you can use GIST indexes and that will speed up your SQL statments a lot.

More about PostGis data tapes [here](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#OpenGISWKBWKT)